# Still @synthesize in later Xcode's?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode7

Using Xcode 7.3.1 (Objective-C).

As we define properties under the Interface, is there still a requirement to 'synthesise' in our Implementation?

Pete

Comment: No, you do not need to synthesise your properties on using xcode > 6.  You just need to use as "_yourProperty".

Comment: @Rohan, thanks for that.